# Unable to get property of a non- object PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm unable to display just display KV for wtype_meteoalarm_name

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/1e6a89f0a3aa092d/alerts/q/zmw:00000.1.16172.json');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);

echo $result->wtype_meteoalarm;
```

Getting error :

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CurlTest\Index.php on line 15

What am I doing that's wrong?

Comment: $result === false. var_dump it and find out

Comment: Why $result instead of $obj?

Comment: ^ 1) you have to call `$obj` instead of `$result`; 2) do a `print_r` of `$obj`, because you can't call `$obj->wtype_meteoalarm`. You have to call something like `$obj->alerts[0]->wtype_meteoalarm` . Do a `print_r` to understand object construct

Comment: print_r($obj->docs[0]->snippet); displays the following error codes:  
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$docs in C:\xampp\htdocs\CurlTest\Index.php on line 19

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CurlTest\Index.php on line 19 http://localhost/CurlTest/Index.php  I'm using the api url (http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?api-key=ab6489d66fac6f23b759d2d47dc7942c:14:68601925)

Comment: @fusion3k  Thanks I was able to get it to work with your help

Comment: @fullyconnected You r welcome